Cannot escape from recurring meeting on Teams
A couple years ago, a coworker in another office location invited me to one instance of a recurring weekly meeting on Teams for a specific issue I needed to discuss with their team. Ever since then, I continue to get a notification in Teams, both on mobile & desktop, any time this recurring meeting starts, even though I'm no longer involved in any way.
I've gone back in Outlook and "Declined" any mention of this meeting I could find. I've searched in Teams and deleted the Chat which was associated with this meeting but I can't find the meeting itself. It no longer shows up on my calendar in Outlook or Teams, even on the date I originally accepted it.
Is anyone aware of any place else I need to look to remove myself from this meeting? I haven't tried clearing cache or reinstalling either app, under the assumption that it's a server-side issue (since it's happening in both apps) but I'll likely try that next...

Has the coworker removed you from the meetings on their side?

@music2myear I emailed them to ask to remove me but didn't get a response. It appears to be a contractor & I'm not sure they're even still with the company tbh!

Do you have an archive/online archive? Have you checked that for the original meeting? Can you Decline the meetings from the correct event?

@music2myear I don't believe I have an archive of that account but I'll check. I did go back & Decline the original invite, but that's the only instance of it I can find. Thanks for the suggestions!
